# A histogram with a bar for each frequency value

Tags: r, histogram

I have a data of 100 rolls of two dice, which can take on 11 values -> {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}

How do I create a histogram in R that would show all 11 of them, each as it's own bar with a label for each one of them.

```
hist(data$X1,breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13),col = "lightblue",xlab="Sum of a roll")
```

Only gives 10 bars.

EDIT:

I did something approximate with moving breaks 0.5 up like so:

```
breaks=c(1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5,11.5,12.5,13.5)
```

Comment: And? What gives your new breaks? Does it answer your question?

Comment: Histograms are for continuous random variables (and your example is discrete). As such a `barplot()` is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Histograms can also be plotted with ggplot. Using @flodel's data:

```
 dd = data.frame(table(sums))
 ggplot(dd)+geom_bar(aes(x=sums, y=Freq), stat='identity')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could just do a barplot of the frequency table:

```
num.dices <- 2L
num.rolls <- 100000L
outcomes <- matrix(sample(1:6, num.dices * num.rolls, replace = TRUE),
                   nrow = num.rolls, ncol = num.dices)
sums <- rowSums(outcomes)
barplot(table(sums))
```

[image]